# Why the default eth0 interface is down by default on CentOS?

Tags: centos, networking

I am already a little bit familiar with Linux distros like Debian or Ubuntu (yeah, very similar) but I wanted to try Red Hat based - CentOS 6.2. I have installed it on my Windows 7 host in VirtualBox and tried to play with it a little.

I have come across a small problem, namely: the default `eth0` interface is down by default. I use the option with NAT (the virtual machine is 'behind' the host). Even if I bring the interface up with `ifconfig eth0 up`, it does not work right away. I get this after bringing the interface up:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:0F:00:8A
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe0f:8a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carriers:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 b)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xd020

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:75:C2:9B
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
[root@centos ~]# _
```

What should be done more to configure the network on CentOS machine?

Comment: There is no `eth1` on your screenshot... Btw, try to run DHCP on your interface: `dhclient eth0`.

Comment: @pbm 1) I changed `eth1` to `eth0` in the description. 2) `dhclient eth0` worked  :) thanks. How can I make it default - run like this after reboot  ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but check out this blog post: http://blog.malaya-digital.org/setup-a-minimal-centos-6-0-64-bit-setup-with-networking/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$IFNAME`. Change the `ONBOOT` line's value to `yes`.

`$IFNAME` will be `eth0` on many EL6 boxes, but on boxes using the [Consistent Network Device Naming](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/ch-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html) scheme, it might be something else, like `en3p1`. This scheme is optional in EL6 but the default in EL7 and newer. Use the command `ip link` to get a list of network interfaces, including the ones that are currently down.

In your future installs, pay more attention. You blew past an option in the network configuration section that let you tell it to bring the interface up on boot. This on-boot option is off by default in EL6 and later, whereas in previous versions, it was on by default.

To make the network interface come up on first boot at install time, go to the `Configure` → `General` tab in the network configuration screen, then check the box labeled `Automatically connect to the network when available`.

As to *why* they changed this, I'd guess security reasons. It gives you a chance to tighten things down a bit from the default setup before bringing up the network interface for the first time, exposing the box to the outside world.

Comment: Precisely the info I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: One small additional step, running `service network restart` after changing the `ONBOOT` to `yes` will bring up the interface.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have a DHCP server in your network, you must set a static IP address. Please consider the following example:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

BOOTPROTO=none
DEVICE=eth0
IPADDR=192.168.1.10 # your IP address
NETMASK=255.255.255.0 # your netmask
NETWORK=192.168.1.0 
ONBOOT=yes
```

Add GATEWAY to your `/etc/sysconfig/network` file:

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
HOSTNAME=hostname.domainname
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1 # your gateway
```

Issue the following command to start network on boot:

```
chkconfig network on
```

Restart your network service:

```
service network restart
```

Take a look at your network interfaces

```
ifconfig
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention what version of CentOS you are using. If I'm not mistaken, 6.x uses NetworkManager by default.

I rarely install X windows on my servers, so NetworkManager is just a pain for me. I disable it and enable the standard 'network' service.

chkconfig NetworkManager off
chkconfig network on

service NetworkManager stop
service network start

To enable DHCP on the interface, run `system-config-network`, edit the appropriate device, save, and restart the network service. Alternately, you can edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and add

`ONBOOT=yes`
`BOOTPROTO=dhcp`

Save changes and restart the network service.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have gathered from experimenting and reading, I agree with uther that Network Manager seems to load by default, but the network service does not.

When I recently had a VM host starting up without eth0 showing up in ifconfig output, it was because I had Network Manager running, network not running, and `NM_CONTROLLED=no` in my `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file.

As soon as I ran `service network restart`, eth0 showed up in ifconfig output.  Rebooting, however, caused it to go away again.

The solution for me appears to be setting `NM_CONTROLLED=no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, then turning on the network service on startup (`chkconfig network on`, as uther and alexnorthsoul point out).  I could (should?) probably turn NetworkManager off by default, but it is working for me now and I am nervous about touching anything else.

By the way, my goal was to get the system to honor the my selected static IP.  When I left NetworkManager running and set `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` (or omitted it), I got eth0 showing up in ifconfig, but the address was a DHCP address, not my static IP.  So turning off NetworkManager spared me from DHCP, and turning on network caused it to load my settings that included the static IP.

I am no sys admin, but rather a developer, so these are not words from a CentOS expert, but just a survivor of configuring the VMs I needed.